# How to copy Mantaflow modifier with keyframed inflow?

Tags: animation, keyframes, linked-data

is there a good or easy way to copy Mantaflow settings from one object to a lot of others when there is a keyframe on the Inflow checkbox? I've got a fracture animation with ca. 250 keyframed objects, now I want to simulate fire with Mantaflow. The fire should start at frame 30, so I set keyframes to the Inflow checkbox.

Now if I want to make all 250 animated meshes light up, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to link the modifier data. The problem is, the keyframes for the Inflow are not copied to the other objects. I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> > *Animation Data* to transfer the keyframes, but then all animation keyframes are copied and all objects move the same. Is there a way to copy only specified animation channels between objects?

I found some similar question where it is suggested to link animation and then make the objects single users, but since there are animation that should not be removed this doesn't seem to work for me.